# What is the relationship between convergence in measure and convergence in Kolmogorove distance?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, measure-theory

Suppose I have a sequence of distribution $F_1, ..., F_n$ convergence to a limiting distribution $F$ in the sense that
\begin{align}
\sup ||F_n - F|| \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} 0 
\end{align}
which is called convergence in K-distance(I think that is the definition, if not correct, please point out).

Now I would like some results related to convergence in measure, for example,
\begin{align}
 \int f(X) dF_n \rightarrow \int f(X) dF
\end{align}
where $f$ is any continuous function.

I know convergence in K-distance may not imply the convergence in measure, so I'm wondering if we could add some constraints, so that K-convergence + constraints implies convergence in measure.